# How to access a child of a child of an element by tagname

Tags: javascript

I need to access some elements that are child of an element without an ID that is a child of an element with an ID. I thought I could access them with the function getElementByTagName but it doesn't work because it is one level to deep. How can I access the third level of elements by tagname?

I tried the following:

```js
// getElementByTagName for first child elements works

var getForm = document.getElementById("parentElement").getElementsByTagName("form").length;
var output = document.getElementById("outputForm").innerHTML = getForm;


// getElementByTagName for second child elements doesn't work

var getInput = document.getElementById("parentElement").getElementsByTagName("form").getElementsByTagName("input").length;
var output = document.getElementById("outputInput").innerHTML = getInput;
```

```html
<div id="parentElement">
  <form>
    First name: <input type="text"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text"><br>
  </form>
</div>
<p id="outputForm"></p>
<p id="outputInput"></p>
```

Please: no jQuery solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` return an `HTMLCollection`, not and `ELement`.

You need to get the first index as

```
var getInput = document.getElementById("parentElement").getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("input").length;
```

**DEMO**

```js
// getElementByTagName for first child elements works

var getForm = document.getElementById("parentElement").getElementsByTagName("form").length;
var output = document.getElementById("outputForm").innerHTML = getForm;


// getElementByTagName for second child elements doesn't work

var getInput = document.getElementById("parentElement").getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("input").length;
var output = document.getElementById("outputInput").innerHTML = getInput;
```

```html
<div id="parentElement">
  <form>
    First name: <input type="text"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text"><br>
  </form>
</div>
<p id="outputForm"></p>
<p id="outputInput"></p>
```

Comment: thanks @gurvinder372 this is exactly what I missed. Thanks for the good explanation and the sample code.

Answer (score 4):

> Use [**`querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), *Returns a list of the elements within the document that match the *specified group of selectors*. The object returned is a **NodeList**.*

You can iterate *NodeList*, to process each element!

```js
var inputs=document.querySelectorAll('#parentElement input');
console.log(inputs);
```

```html
<div id="parentElement">
  <form>
    First name: <input type="text"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text"><br>
  </form>
</div>
<p id="outputForm"></p>
<p id="outputInput"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName returns a Collection. You have to use one element of it. Try this: `getElementsByTagName("form")[0]`

```
var getInput = document.getElementById("parentElement").getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("input").length;
var output = document.getElementById("outputInput").innerHTML = getInput;
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName("form") return a collection of elements, you could find "inner elements" only on a single element.

Try to add the index 0 to access his subelements:

```
var getInput = document.getElementById("parentElement").getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("input").length;
```